# Bad escape /I with pandas str contains

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In a simple app I'm making the user selects a folder which is stored as a string. I have a df where one of the columns are file names which are complete paths to the files stored as well as some text I don't want. I want to only select the rows in the df that have the same path as the folder that was selected

The df looks like this

```
    File Name
1   D:\This\is\a\file\path\I\edited\008SMP
2   D:\This\is\a\file\path\I\edited\009SMP
3   D:\This\is\a\file\path\I\edited\010SMP
4   "Action on Failure"
5   Total Dil.
6   Max. Daily Dose
7   File Name
8   D:\This\is\a\file\path\I\edited\011SMP
....
```

So if `foldername=r"D:\This\is\a\file\path\I\edited\"`

I only want to select rows where the file name contains the folder name. The output should be this.

```
    File Name
1   D:\This\is\a\file\path\I\edited\008SMP
2   D:\This\is\a\file\path\I\edited\009SMP
3   D:\This\is\a\file\path\I\edited\010SMP
8   D:\This\is\a\file\path\I\edited\011SMP
....
```

However, when I try

```
df=df[df["File Name"].str.contains(foldername)]
```

I get error: `error: bad escape \I`

And for some reason when I try to only compare a portion of the foldername it returns false even though there are rows that contain it

```
df["File Name"].str.contains(foldername[:10])
Out[43]: 
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
11    False
23    False
35    False
59    False
60    False
61    False
62    False
63    False
64    False
65    False
66    False
67    False
68    False
70    False
81    False
92    False
Name: File Name, dtype: bool

if foldername[:10] in df.iloc[0,1]:
    print("y")
    
y
```

Comment: `\` is an escape character. You should use raw string `foldername=r"D:\This\is\a\file\path\I\edited\"`

Comment: @QuangHoang I do and I get the same error. But i'll fix the typo in post thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add "regex=False"

```
df=df[df["File Name"].str.contains(foldername, regex=False)]
```